# Import keras.datasets not working

Tags: python, linux, python-import, theano, keras

I have keras installed on my linux machine, but when I try to import a dataset from the keras.datasets I get an error that it cannot find it.

So for example:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
```

I get the error

> ImportError: No module named keras.datasets

I installed keras using `pip install` and it installed successfully.

Comment: Do you have multiple Python versions? For which one did you installed keras?

Comment: Thanks good question. Indeed I have multiple versions of python, but I installed it for 2.7 and tried it out with 2.7 too.

Comment: And if I look in the folder with the packages, it is there also:
`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/datasets$ ls
cifar100.py   cifar10.py   cifar.py   data_utils.py   imdb.py   __init__.py   mnist.py   reuters.py
cifar100.pyc  cifar10.pyc  cifar.pyc  data_utils.pyc  imdb.pyc  __init__.pyc  mnist.pyc  reuters.pyc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Indeed the problem was that I had multiple versions of Python.
>
> Removing Anaconda Python and installing all libraries using pip / apt-get instead of conda solved my problem.

I found this to be true but it is not necessary to delete anaconda.
I had the same issue but with multiple python versions. However, i created an environment that only used the Anaconda version (while in that environment). In terminal (on mac and other suitable terminals), type/copy

`conda create -n dataweekends python=2.7 pandas scikit-learn jupyter matplotlib`

dataweekends is simply the name of the environment you created. To access this, just use the command

`source activate dataweekends`

Be mindful that you might (probably) have to reinstall dependencies once in that new environment.

I got this trick from here "https://www.dataweekends.com/blog/2017/03/09/set-up-your-mac-for-deep-learning-with-python-keras-and-tensorflow"

I would also recommend setting up different environments for each project you do in python.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have `keras.py` or `keras.pyc` in the current working directory? If so, this will mess up the imports. Try **renaming the file** and/or **deleting `keras.pyc`**.

Comment: No I didn't. That seems like a very bad thing to have.

Comment: saved my day!! I named my file as 'keras.py' and got the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment from Selcuk which got me on the right track.

Indeed the problem was that I had multiple versions of Python. 
I followed some online instructions to installing Keras which recommended installing MiniConda/Conda/Anaconda which is its own version of python. So I had two Python2.7 versions installed:

- Normal Linux Python 2.7
- Anaconda Python 2.7

Removing Anaconda Python and installing all libraries using `pip` / `apt-get` instead of `conda` solved my problem.